# My loop code on jquery doesn't work with .each inside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this.

```
<input  type="text" name="1" class = "inp<?=$p?> ">
<input  type="text" name="2" class = "inp<?=$p?> ">
<input  type="text" name="3" class = "inp<?=$p?> ">
<input  type="text" name="4" class = "sum<?=$p?> ">
```

Here the jquery code

```
$('.inp0').keyup(function(){       
var sum = 0;
var ave = 0;
$('.inp0').each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
});
 ave  = sum/3;
$('.sum0').val(ave.toFixed(2));
});
```

and it work properly but just for 1 row of input form.

if i do loop to my jquery code like

```
for(x=0;x<5;x++)
{*jquery code here*}
```

and change jquery selector to `$('.inp'+x)`, only 5th row that can work but not for row 1 to 4.
can someone help me ? thanks before

Comment: Just use a common class to all the input fields, no need to have separate classes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1wbsheh6/1/ ?

Comment: do you mean, you have 5 sets of elements like this?

Comment: if so https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1wbsheh6/3/?

Comment: @ArunPJohny i have many sets, not just inp, but
inp1, inp1, inp1, sum1
inp2, inp2, inp2, sum2
if i do it manualy it work, but if i do it by loop it doens't work

Comment: @ArunPJohny dude, thanks ! :*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the elemnets by attributes and use that to select the elements like

```js
$('.inp').keyup(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var ave = 0;
  var grp = $(this).data('grp');
  $('.inp[data-grp="' + grp + '"]').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val() || 0;
  });
  ave = sum / 3;
  $('.sum[data-grp="' + grp + '"]').val(ave.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="1" data-grp="0" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="2" data-grp="0" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="3" data-grp="0" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="4" data-grp="0" class="sum">
<br />
<input type="text" name="1" data-grp="1" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="2" data-grp="1" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="3" data-grp="1" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="4" data-grp="1" class="sum">
<br />
<input type="text" name="1" data-grp="2" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="2" data-grp="2" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="3" data-grp="2" class="inp">
<input type="text" name="4" data-grp="2" class="sum">
<br />
```

---

Another way

```js
$('.inp').keyup(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var ave = 0;
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  $tr.find('.inp').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val() || 0;
  });
  ave = sum / 3;
  $tr.find('.sum').val(ave.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="1" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="2" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="3" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="4" class="sum">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="1" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="2" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="3" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="4" class="sum">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="1" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="2" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="3" class="inp">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="4" class="sum">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('[class^="inp"]').keyup(function(){       
var sum = 0;
var ave = 0;
var index = $(this).attr('class').split('p')[1];
$('.inp'+index).each(function(){
    sum += $(this).val();
});
 ave  = sum/3;

$('.sum'+index).val(ave.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just 1 input classed 'inp0'. Use a common class for all inputs and in the selector.